# Adding a Web Reference for SharePoint in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, asmx

Whenever I add a web reference for any Sharepoint web service in VS 2008, the preview window while adding the web reference shows the proper method names:
Note CreateFolder:

Before: [alt text http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/5286/vs20081bq7.png](http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/5286/vs20081bq7.png)

And after, the CreateFolder method is not there

[After http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/3530/vs20082be5.png](http://img134.imageshack.us/img134/3530/vs20082be5.png)

I looked over the documentation at
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774480.aspx) but it appears I am using it properly.
Can anybody point out my mistake?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a reference to the Dws object in your code. Otherwise you can only see the static methods/types.

Try

```
DocumentWorkspace dw = new DocumentWorkspace();
dw.CreateFolder();
```

Not that normally I need to get a reference to a specific sites dws services, so adding the following code helps

```
dw.Credentials = [get the appropriate credentials, most often System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials];
dw.Url = [basesiteurl] + "/_vti_bin/dw.asmx";
```

Comment: It worked with this modification: DocumentWorkspace.Dws dw = new DocumentWorkspace.Dws();  Thank you!

Also, I'm not sure what you mean by adding the credentials and url to the Document Workspace object.  What does that afford me?

Comment: Edit, I see I needed the credentials (which is odd, because none are needed to upload, but the URL was already added when I added the web reference, so I don't think I need to add it again.

Comment: If you are using the lists.asmx, you will want to point to the asmx of the site you want the lists from for example.